# Windows10 или linux mint

Tags: linux, windows

Здраствуйте! что лучше для программиста бэкендчика,и в чем разница?Если по подробней было бы лучше!Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотря что вам больше по душе linux или windows.
Разница колоссальна, можно целый трактат написать.

## Linux

Плюсы:

- бесплатно
- основанная ось для серверов
- customizable
- и т.д.

Минусы:

- Довольно трудно бывает подключить внешние  устройства, типа принтеров, сканеров т.к. драйверов мало. Впрочем все можно "порешать".
- Поддержка в основном "сообществом". Bпрочем это
  иногда плюс ;)

## Windows

Плюсы:

- Поддержка Microsoft.
- Более популярна для десктопа.
- и т.д.

Минусы:

- платная
- не-customizable
- и т.д.

В принципе тут можно очень много чего сказать, но все это — уже [есть в гугле](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+vs+linux&oq=windows+vs+linux&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l7.3647j0j7&client=ubuntu&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). А вы выберете то, что более вам удобно.

**P.S** Кстати я использую Linux.